# A man is rowing a boat upstream is at rest with respect to shore is he doing any work

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, work

Is the man doing any work or not when is rowing a boat upstream? I m confused That Okay he's at rest with respect to Shore but at some sites it can be seen that Yes he is doing work then how he is doing work while he is at rest with respect to shore ? If he is doing work Then In which direction it's done ✅

Comment: What do you think would happen if he **didn't** row?

Comment: People voting to close - This is conceptual question. He is not asking how to solve anything.

Comment: A legitimate and interesting conceptual question. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 5):

A favorite textbook ([Chabay and Sherwood](https://matterandinteractions.org/)) emphasizes identifying clearly which parts of the problem are your “system” and which parts are the “surroundings.” To do mechanical work, using the formal definition

$$
W=\int\mathrm d\vec x\cdot\vec F,
$$

the boundary between the system and its surroundings must move; otherwise the integral is trivially zero.

If our system is “the boat,” a stationary object, then the work done is zero.  What are the relevant parts of the boat’s surroundings? The water in the river exerts a downstream force on the bow of the boat, but the acceleration of the boat is zero.  The acceleration vanishes because of a counterbalancing force on the [oarlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oarlock), where the oar pivots on the gunwale.  (Dear non-English-speakers: boat jargon is weird, and a mariner will surely tell me soon that I’m using it wrong, but that he likes the cut of my [jib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jib).)

What if our “system” is the oar? The oar interacts with there pieces of its surroundings:

1. the stationary oarlock
2. the water, where the paddle moves downstream
3. the rower, who pulls upstream on the handle

The boundary between the “system” (the oar) and these “surroundings”  is non-stationary in the hands of the rower and in the water.  So when you ask

> Is the man doing any work or not when is rowing a boat upstream?

the answer is that the *man* is doing work on the *oar*. That involves considering the *rower* as the “system.” But the work done on the *oar* doesn’t explain why the boat remains stationary: you can wave the oar around to no effect. The insight is that the *oar* is doing work on the *river*, remaining stationary by forcing the flow downstream of the boat to be slightly faster than the flow upstream of the boat.

In your title, you make the common mistake of implicitly considering the “system” as “boat plus man plus oar,” which you refer to as “stationary” even though the boundary between the system and its surroundings changes shape as the oars move.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the man doing any work or not when is rowing a boat upstream?

Yes. It is easier to look at power which is the rate of work. $P=\vec F \cdot \vec v$ where $\vec v$ is the velocity of the material at the point of application of the force $\vec F$. The man is applying a force on the handle of the oars and the velocity of the material of the handle is in the same direction as the force. So $P=\vec F \cdot \vec v > 0$ and therefore the man does work on the oars.

Answer (score 0):

$W = Fd$

Here are a few more questions that might help.

A man on shore relaxes in a beach chair. Is he doing work?

A man in an inner tube floats down the river. Is he doing work?

A man pedals a bicycle downstream, keeping up with the inner tube. He overcomes wind resistance and friction. Is he doing work?

A man rows a boat in the ocean out of sight of land. He doesn't know which way the ocean currents are flowing. He overcomes drag from the water. Is he doing work?

A man is hovering in a rocket. The rocket engine exerts a large force on the exhaust gasses, pushing them out the back. Is the rocket engine doing work?

Comment: what about a hovering rocket?